# Materialize Facebook Icon

Tags: html, materialize

I am trying to get a facebook icon on my website using Materialize and I am following this code example as it seems to be the only source I have found about it and it is not working properly

```
<i class="material-icons" id="footer-email">email</i>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-floating social facebook">
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign in with facebook</a>
```

and it shows up like the image attached. [icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJQt1.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The facebook icon which you are trying to integrate is not part of `materialize` framework and you will have to download `materialize-social` from the below url and need to include the library in your code.

https://github.com/TerryMooreII/materialize-social

Hope this helps!.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://materialdesignicons.com

[Here](https://materialdesignicons.com/getting-started) is a guide on how to use the icons

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helpful!. You can check also

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <i class="material-icons">facebook</i>
</body>
</html>
```

https://materializecss.com/icons.html